# Error: 'Result<Data, FourSquareError>' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: ios, swift, rest, swift5

I'm trying to call the API and when I pass the value to the result variable it gives me an error. I also get this error on the func mapError function below.

Any idea on why am I getting this error?

Thanks in advance

> 'Result[Data, FourSquareError]' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
>
> 'Result[Data, E]' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

**The errors are on these lines:**

```
let result = Result<Data, FourSquareError>(value: data, error:
          translatedError)

return Result<Value, E>(value)

return Result<Value, E>(try transform (error))
```

**Here's the full code:**

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]

enum FourSquareError: Error {
    case couldNotCreateURL
    case networkError(Error)
    case serverError(errorType: String, errorDetail: String)
    case couldNotParseData
}

func createURL(endpoint: String, parameters: [String: String]) -> URL? {
    let baseURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/"

    // We convert the parameters dictionary in an array of URLQueryItems
    var queryItems = parameters.map { pair -> URLQueryItem in
        return URLQueryItem(name: pair.key, value: pair.value)
    }

    // Add default parameters to query
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "v", value: apiVersion))
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "client_id", value: clientId))
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "client_secret", value: clientSecret))

    var components = URLComponents(string: baseURL + endpoint)
    components?.queryItems = queryItems
    return components?.url
}
```

```
func getVenues(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping
     (Result<[JSON], FourSquareError>) -> Void) {
      let parameters = [
          "ll": "\(latitude),\(longitude)",
          "intent": "browse",
          "radius": "250"
      ]

      guard let url = createURL(endpoint: "venues/search", parameters:
     parameters)
          else {
              completion(Result.failure(.couldNotCreateURL))
              return
      }
       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response,
          error in
               let translatedError = error.map { FourSquareError.networkError($0) }
               let result = Result<Data, FourSquareError>(value: data, error:
          translatedError)
                   // Parsing Data to JSON
                   .flatMap { data in
                       do {
                           return Result.success(try parseData(data))
                       } catch {
                           return Result.failure(.unexpectedError(error))
                       }
                   }
                   // Check for server errors
                   .flatMap { (json: JSON) -> Result<JSON, FourSquareError> in
                       do {
                           return Result.success(try validateResponse(json: json))
                       } catch {
                           return Result.failure(.unexpectedError(error))
                       }
                   }
                   // Extract venues
                   .flatMap { (json: JSON) -> Result<[JSON], FourSquareError> in
                       do {
                           return Result.success(try extractVenues(json: json))
                       } catch {
                           return Result.failure(.unexpectedError(error))
                       }
               }

               completion(result)
           }

           task.resume()
    }
```

```
extension Result {
    public func mapError<E: Error>(_ transform: (ErrorType) throws -> E) rethrows -> Result<Value, E> {
        switch self {
        case .success(let value):
            return Result<Value, E>(value)
        case .failure(let error):
            return Result<Value, E>(try transform (error))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Result is an enum so you can construct it. You can only instantiate a `Result` instance through one of it's two cases: `failure` or `success`. For example:

```
let result: Result<Data, FourSquareError> = .success(Data())
```

or

```
let result: Result<Data, FourSquareError> = .failure(FourSquareError.whatever)
```

Comment: I tried to do that and then I got another error: `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'success' .`.  The same for both success and failure. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed after using this solution. `extension Result {
    
    init(value: Value?, error: ErrorType?) {
        if let error = error {
            self = .failure(error)
        } else if let value = value {
            self = .success(value)
        } else {
            fatalError("Could not create Result")
        }
    }
}`

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what's failing in your code. The code in the solution I posted compiles just fine for me.

Comment: @Marcelo This is an entirely different issue than the original question, but, you need to specify the return type in your first flatMap closure: `.flatMap { data -> Result<JSON, FourSquareError> in`

Comment: Thanks. I just need to fix this error in the first flatMap that you mentioned. Value of type 'Result<Data, RequestServices3.FourSquareError>' has no member 'flatMap'. Any idea?